# Chef error in tutorial: Cannot find a resource for mysql_database on ubuntu version 10.04

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am brand new to Chef and trying to walk through and understand a tutorial: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Build+a+Django+Stack.

Very early on, when trying to launch the first instance on the AWS server, I get this error: http://pastie.org/8068021

I have given Google a good go, but I cannot find a solution that is simple enough for a beginning Chef-er to understand so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting these statements in your **site-cookbooks/main/metadata.rb**:

```
depends 'build-essential'
depends 'openssl' #depends on build-essential
depends 'mysql' # depends on openssl
depends 'database' #depends on mysql
```

I was running into the same error, and it was because I'd forgotten to add the *database* cookbook dependency.

After you add the *database* cookbook dependency, you might run into one of these errors on subsequent cooking attempts:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook aws not found.
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook postgresql not found.
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook xfs not found.
```

Thats just because the *database* cookbook has its own dependencies. You can add the dependent cookbooks if appropriate, or if not, just comment them out of **cookbooks/database/metadata.rb**:

```
depends "mysql", ">= 1.3.0"
# depends "postgresql", ">= 1.0.0"  
# depends "aws"  
# depends "xfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the metadata.rb of *database* cookbook, you will see that it depends on some other books.

```
depends "mysql", ">= 1.3.0"
depends "postgresql", ">= 1.0.0"
depends "aws"
depends "xfs"
```

That means in order to operate, it requires these cookbooks to be also accessible. *mysql_database* is not a standard resource. It is described in mysql cookbook. (The naming convention of such resources are [cookbook_name]_[resource_name]. Seek for [LWRP](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_custom.html) for more info on that.)

Comment: I already have that cookbook. I manually added again to make sure there was no mistake and it still failed.